# OpenSSH on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS not working asking for password and publickey

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, password

So I’ve got a new PowerEdge R810 everything working fine just when I try to SSH into the machine using my login details that work on the machine it says Permission Denied (password, publickey) in the `sshd_config` and `ssh_config` they both have the `PubKuy Auth` setting set to no and the password one is set to yes, all the other settings are # out. I would put it here but I cannot copy and paste it…
Any ideas if there is anything else I need to do to get the SSH working without publickey?

Comment: Also just to add I used the root account to get into the files and they were in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and /etc/ssh/ssh_config also I’ve set the Root Access to no and PubKey Auth to no.. other settings are default ones marked out with the # also this is the LTS Server version

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].

Comment: See more information - use `ssh -v`.

Comment: Sorry about that and I will try that now one second please.

Comment: Just FYI there shouldn't be any need to edit any configuration files to get password-based SSH to work for non-`root` accounts - that should work right out of the box

Comment: It seems like after a bit of testing you do have to, this is using a ISO Burned USB for 20.04 latest version LTS and yeah tried 3 times and on 2 different machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so for this to work on Ubuntu 20.04 you have to make sure you set AllowUsers to your own username. When you setup the system it won’t set every user by default as I’ve seen by multi 20.04 testing setups..